# Why user-defined conversion is not implicitly taking place on the calling object

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Consider the following class definitions of `A` and `B`:

```
class A {
public:
   void func() const {}
};

class B {
public:
   // user-defined conversion operator to A
   operator A() const { return a_; }
private:
   A a_;
};
```

The class `A` defines a public member function called `func()`. The class `B` does not, but it does define a *user-defined conversion operator* to the type `A`. This way, an instance of `B` can be *converted into* an instance of `A`. The following code works as expected:

```
B b;
static_cast<A>(b).func(); // call func() on temporary instance of A
```

In the code above, the conversion operator is implicitly called by means of the `static_cast` *named cast*.

Note that the conversion operator in `B` is not specified as `explicit` in order to allow implicit conversions as well.
However, the following code does not compile:

```
B b;
b.func(); // <-- error: 'class B' has no member named 'func'
```

Just as the error message says, class `B` has no member named `func`, but class `A` does, and class `B` does have a user-defined conversion operator to `A`. The user-defined conversion operator is **not** implicitly called in this case.

Why is the conversion not being **implicitly** done?

Comment: What if it has 30 conversions operators? Should a compiler try all of them? And what if it can be converted to two types that both have that method? How could a compiler guess what you are trying to do exactly? Pretend that you are explicit about your intents make sense indeed.

Comment: @skypjack yes, I think the compiler should try all of them and only generate an error message if there is an ambiguity.

Comment: Then fortunately the committee decided differently. ;-)

Comment: It's an interesting thought experiment, though, to consider the implications of a compiler trying all possible conversions.

Comment: @skypjack That's a strange argument. If you write `b(1)` or `b+1` etc., the compiler will in fact try all 30 conversion operators.  There's just something different about the `.` operator.

Comment: @aschepler The way it moves is opposite in this case. `b(1)` looks for a function named `b` that accepts an `int` (well, simplified, but you get the mean). What OP wants is instead that the compiler looks for all the conversion operators, try the casts and looks for the right method and then what if the new type has conversion operators for itself? What about circular conversions? It quickly breaks everything, right? :-)

Comment: @skypjack If `b` has class type, `b(1)` looks for both `b.operator()` and all (30?) conversion functions of `b` that result in a pointer or reference to function type (but not another class type that has `operator()`).  Only one implicit conversion per argument is allowed, of course, which answers the self-conversion and circular conversion issues.

Comment: @aschepler Yeah, the purpose of my _simplified_ wording was to avoid details for both of us knew them at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conversion isn't considered for member access (§5.2.5/2 [expr.ref]).

> In either case,
>   the *id-expression* shall name a member of the class or of one of its base classes

Here the *id-expression* is `func()`

So the compiler considers that `func` must be a member of `B` or a class that `B` derives from. Implicit conversion to other types that might have a `func` member is not considered.